# example/index.html.erb is not displayed right

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

```css
body {
 padding-top: 5%;
 padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.title {
 padding-top: 40px;
 min-height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.notice,
.alert {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

h1 {
 padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.navbar {
 background: white;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #D70000;
}

.icon-bar {
 color: #D70000;
}

.navbar-brand {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: 20px 15px;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.navbar-brand a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: 20px 15px;
}

.navbar-brand a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #D70000;
}

.footer {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.metric {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

#bg {
 background-image: image_url("redvinyl.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size:cover;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-img {
 width: 600px;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
}

.carousel-caption {
 color: ghostwhite;
 text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
 font-family: Futura, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 4.2em;
 margin: auto;
 padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.form-row {
 margin: auto;
 width: 60%;
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 1%;
}

.form-entry {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
}

.auth-links {
 margin: auto;
 height: auto;
 width: 20%;
}

.padding {
 padding-top: 25px;
}

.burning {
 color: black;
 letter-spacing: .25em;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.navsearch {
 margin-top: 12px;
}

body {
 padding-top: 5%;
 padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.title {
 padding-top: 40px;
 min-height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.notice,
.alert {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

h1 {
 padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.navbar {
 background: white;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #D70000;
}

.icon-bar {
 color: #D70000;
}

.navbar-brand {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: 20px 15px;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.navbar-brand a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: 20px 15px;
}

.navbar-brand a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #D70000;
}

.footer {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.metric {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

#bg {
 background-image: image_url("redvinyl.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size:cover;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-img {
 width: 600px;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
}

.carousel-caption {
 color: ghostwhite;
 text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
 font-family: Futura, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 4.2em;
 margin: auto;
 padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.form-row {
 margin: auto;
 width: 60%;
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 1%;
}

.form-entry {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
}

.auth-links {
 margin: auto;
 height: auto;
 width: 20%;
}

.padding {
 padding-top: 25px;
}

.burning {
 color: black;
 letter-spacing: .25em;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.navsearch {
 margin-top: 12px;
}
```

My index.html.erb page is not displayer correctly as you can see in the attached file. It must be a front end issue.I am sending the index and a partial along with a printscreen of the problem[gaps in index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btE71.jpg)

```js
# _product.html.erb
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 product">
 <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: "img-responsive img-rounded") %>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <h1><strong><%= product.name %></strong></h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-12">
   <p><%= product.description %></p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-12">
   <p>$<%= product.price %></p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-12 crud1">
   <%= link_to 'Show', product %>
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %>
   <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
 </div>
</div>
```

```css
.product-show {
 padding-top: 3%;
}

.paycrud {
 text-align: center;
}

.buttoncenter {
 text-align: center;
}

.crud1 {
 text-align: center;
}

.paginate {
 text-align: center;
}

.rating {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
# index.html.erb
<div class="container-fluid title">
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <div class="row">
    <h1 id="vinyls">Listing Products</h1>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <% cache(cache_key_for_products) do %>
        <%= render @products %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="buttoncenter"><%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path, class: "btn btn-default" %></div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's a css problem. How does your css look like?

Comment: thank you for your reply. i have included my css file as well

Comment: I was more thinking about the css of your grid system. The error obviously occurs when one element is smaller then the others in a row.

Comment: edited again.. thank you